# I have a segmentation fault with my code

Tags: file, segmentation-fault

This program is designed for reading in file names and displaying them but I have a segmentation fault. I tried to change many things in the code to get it working, but it seems that the array for struct NameRecords records[150000] is my problem. If I change the value to 74000, the code will run, but if I increase to 150000, the number I need, it wont run. 
    Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

//structure for storing names in the files
struct NameRecord {
    char name[31];
    int year;
    int frequency;
};

void allCaps(char a[]); //capitalizes all of the characters of s
int getRawData(FILE* fp, struct NameRecord records[], int currSize);//reads in files of the two csv files
void setYearTotals(struct NameRecord records[], int size, int  yearRangeTotal[]);//calclulates the total population between the 4 year gap
void setNameYearTotals(char theName[], struct NameRecord records[], int size, int nameTotal[]); //stores the frequency for the names in a 4 year difference
void getPerHundredThousand(int nameTotal[], int yearRangeTotal[], double perHundredThousand[]);//gets the name frequency per hundred births for a given year range
void printData(double perHundredThousand[]);//print the frequency of the name per years
void graphPerHundredThousand(double perHundredThousand[]);//display the frequency in a graph like way

main () {
    //declarations to be used to get data from user and run functions
    int this=0,me,size;
    int yearTotal[1000];
    int range[150];
    int nameTotal[150];
    struct NameRecord records[150000];
    char name[30];
    char theName[150];
    char answer;
    double thousand[150];
    FILE* fp;
    do {
        printf("Enter a name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]",name);
        allCaps(name);
        me = getRawData(fp,records,this);   
        setYearTotals(records,me,yearTotal);
        setNameYearTotals(theName,records,me,nameTotal);
        getPerHundredThousand(nameTotal,range,thousand);
        printData(thousand);
        graphPerHundredThousand(thousand);
        printf("Do you wish to check another name (Y/N): ");
        scanf(" %c",&answer);
    } while(answer!='n' && answer !='N');
}


void allCaps(char a[]) {
//uses toupper function in order to capitalize the entered string
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
        a[i] = toupper(a[i]);
    }
}

int getRawData(FILE* fp, struct NameRecord records[], int currSize) {
    //reads the file names from both male and female records
    int i, run =0,temp,j;
    currSize=0;
    do {
        if (run==0) {
            fp = fopen("malebabynames.csv", "r");
            if(fp == NULL)
                printf("File not found:\"malebabynames.csv!\"");
            else {
                while(fscanf(fp,"%d,%[^,],%d", &records[currSize].year, records[currSize].name, &records[currSize].frequency)!= -1) { //condition to continue reading until end of file is reached
                    currSize++;
                } 
                fclose(fp);
            }
            run++;
        } else if(run==1) {
            fp = fopen("femalebabynames.csv", "r");//change to csv
            if(fp == NULL)
                printf("File not found:\"femalebabynames.csv!\"");
            else {
                while(fscanf(fp,"%d,%[^,],%d", &records[currSize].year, records[currSize].name, &records[currSize].frequency)!= -1) {
                    currSize++;
                } 
                fclose(fp);
            }
        }
    } while(run == 1); //continues till both files are read
    //array to sort the file based on year
    for(i=0; i < currSize; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < currSize; j++) {
            if (records[i].year > records[j].year) {
                temp = records[i].year;
                records[i].year = records[j].year;
                records[j].year = temp;
            }
        }
    }
        return currSize;

}

void setYearTotals(struct NameRecord records[], int size, int yearRangeTotal[]  ) {
    //yearRangeTotal[0] holds the total population between 1921-1925. 4 year gap
    int k,i,population=0,counter=0;
    //loop to hold the frequency
    for(k=0; k<size; k++){
        for(i=0; i < 4; i++) {
            population += records[counter].frequency; //equal to population every 4 years
            counter++;
        }
        yearRangeTotal[k] = population;
        population=0;
    }

}

void setNameYearTotals(char theName[], struct NameRecord records[], int size, int nameTotal[]) {
    // nameTotal[0]. stores the frequency for theName for a 4 year difference
    int i,j,counter=0;
    //checks for the name, stores in counter and continues checking
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        theName[i] = &records[i].name;
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if(theName[i] == &records[j].name)
                counter++;
        }
        nameTotal[i] = counter;
        counter=0;
    }
}

void getPerHundredThousand(int nameTotal[], int yearRangeTotal[], double perHundredThousand[]) {
    int i,j,k;
    double keep;
    //gets the name for the frequency of births for a given year period
    for(i=0; i < 50; i++) {
        keep = 10000* (nameTotal[i]/yearRangeTotal[i]);
        perHundredThousand[i] = keep;
    }
    printData(perHundredThousand);
    graphPerHundredThousand(perHundredThousand);
}

void printData(double perHundredThousand[]) {
    //print the data starting from 1921 till 2010
    int year = 1921,i;
    printf("Frequency Per Hundred Thousand Births\n");
    printf("=====================================\n");
    for(i=0; i != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%d - %d: %lf\n",year,year+4,perHundredThousand[i]);
        year+=4;
    }
}

void graphPerHundredThousand(double perHundredThousand[]) {
    int i,j,temp=0,year=2010;
    double stars,k;
    double base;
    //sorts the array from 2010 to 1921 to get the smallest non-zero value
    for(i=0; i != '\0'; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < '\0'; j++) {
            if (perHundredThousand[i] > perHundredThousand[j]) { 
                temp = perHundredThousand[i];
                perHundredThousand[i] = perHundredThousand[j];
                perHundredThousand[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    base = perHundredThousand[0];
    printf("                Graph\n"); 
    printf("=====================================\n");
    //calculates the stars needed in each year based on calculation of the smallest non-zero value calculated from upabove 
    for(i=0; i != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%d - %d: %lf\n",year,year-4);
        stars=perHundredThousand[i]/base;
        k = ceil(stars);
        for(i=0; i < k; i++) {
            if (k == 0)
                break;
            else {
                printf("*");
            }
        }
        year-=4;
    }

}
```

Comment: This might help: http://www.google.com/search?q=gdb+debugger+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You're almost certainly overflowing the stack.  By making the "records" array a pre-defined part of the main() function, you're putting a minimum of 5850000 bytes of data on the stack -- which is almost certainly larger than the default stack size your compiler/linker/OS is allocating.  You've got three options: 1) make the "records" array global (which puts it on the much larger heap), 2) allocate the "records" array at runtime using an appropriate memory-allocation function, or 3) figure out how to have your compiler make the stack larger.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've had a few exams. I tried this, but now my program hangs and doesn't go past entering a name when I make records a global array

Comment: You really should be using a debugger for this: finding crashes is easy when the debugger shows you the exact line of code that crashed, and infinite loops are easy to spot when you can pause program execution in the middle of the loop.  If for some reason you can't use a debugger, look up "printf debugging" to find an alternate way of following program flow.